# Maximum Treewidth of a Graph with $m$ Edges

Tags: reference-request, parameterized-complexity, treewidth

What is the maximum treewidth of a graph with $m$ edges? In other 
words, what is the correct growth for the following function?

$\alpha(m) = max\{\mathrm{treewidth}(G): G \mbox{ has $m$ edges}\}$.

Clearly $\alpha(m) = \Omega(\sqrt{m})$, which is attained 
by cliques with $\Omega(\sqrt{m})$ vertices and by 
by $\Omega(\sqrt{m})\times \Omega(\sqrt{m})$ grids.

Is this also the maximum?

Comment: cubic expanders have linear treewidth.

Comment: @PsySp Could you please post this as an answer with a reference to the fact that expanders have linear treewidth?

Comment: PS: asked the question about small $m$ here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53806/what-is-the-smallest-graph-of-treewidth-k-having-less-edges-than-the-k1-cli

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are bounded degree (in fact even cubic i.e. 3-regular) expanders on $m$ vertices with treewidth at least $\epsilon \cdot m$, for some constant $\epsilon > 0$. See Section 2 in:

Martin Grohe, Dániel Marx:
*On tree width, bramble size, and expansion*. J. Comb. Theory, Ser. B 99(1): 218-228 (2009)

Basically, they prove something much stronger: large vertex expansion is *the only* reason on why the treewidth can be as much as linear (in the number of vertices, but bounded degree graphs have linear number of edges).

Comment: Regarding your statement, 'There are bounded degree (in fact even cubic i.e., 3-regular) expanders on \( m \) vertices with treewidth at least $ \epsilon \cdot m $,' are you implying that there exist certain bounded degree expander graphs whose treewidth is linear in $m $, or are you asserting that the treewidth of all bounded degree expander graphs is linear in $m$?

Answer (score 7):

The best known upper bound of the treewidth in terms of the number of edges of a graph is as follows: the pathwidth (and therefore also the treewidth) of any graph on $n$ vertices and $m$ edges is at most $13 m / 75 + o(n)$.

Alexander D. Scott and Gregory B. Sorkin. Linear-programming design and analysis of fast algorithms for Max 2-CSP, Discrete Optimization 4 (2007), no. 3-4, 260-287. https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0604080

Joachim Kneis, Daniel Mölle, Stefan Richter, and Peter Rossmanith, A bound on the pathwidth of sparse graphs with applications to exact algorithms, SIAM Journal on Discrete Mathematics 23 (2009), no. 1, 407-427.