# What is the smallest graph of treewidth $k$ having less edges than the $(k+1)$-clique?

Tags: graph-theory, treewidth, extremal-combinatorics

[Treewidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth) is a graph parameter measuring how close a graph is to being a tree. I am interested in what is the minimal number of edges required for a graph to have treewidth $k$.

A natural family of graphs to consider are the [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)): a clique on $k+1$ vertices has treewidth $k$, and has $k (k+1) / 2$ edges. However, asymptotically, there are graphs of treewidth $k$ whose number of edges is linear rather than quadratic, e.g., cubic expanders as mentioned in [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/39071/maximum-treewidth-of-a-graphs-with-m-edges). So cliques are not optimal. My question is: **what is the smallest example of a graph of treewidth $k$ having less edges than the $(k+1)$-clique?**

I have checked experimentally that all graphs of 14 edges or less have treewidth at most 4, so they do not beat the 6-clique which has 15 edges and treewidth 5. Hence, the smallest treewidth for which I do not know the answer is 6. Specifically: the 7-clique has 21 edges and treewidth 6, but **is there a graph of treewidth 6 having 20 edges or less?**

(Note that we could ask the same question of the minimal number of *vertices* required for a graph to have treewidth $k$, but then it is uninteresting: you need $k+1$ vertices for a graph to have treewidth $k$, and this is achieved by the $(k+1)$-clique.)

Comment: Related: having treewidth of $O(n)$ where $n$ is the number of vertices is known to be equivalent to having large expansion and bounded degree, see [1, Theorem 8]. The probabilistic construction of expanders would give you a graph with treewidth $k$ with $O(k)$ vertices whp. [1] Böttcher, Julia, et al. "Bandwidth, expansion, treewidth, separators and universality for bounded-degree graphs." European Journal of Combinatorics 31.5 (2010)

Comment: Re the previous comment. The quantifiers are not quite correct I believe. $\Omega(1)$ vertex expansion suffices for $\Omega(n)$ treewidth. And there exist bounded degree graphs (in particular degree 3) with $\Omega(1)$ vertex expansion. Edge and vertex expansion are related by the maximum degree, and hence one obtains vertex expansion automatically from edge expansion if degree is fixed (such as 3).